# Parsing IP address then changing it? Batch

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I'm attempting to use the local IP address as a variable which words perfectly fine with the following line

```
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping %computername% -n 1 ^| D:\Windows\system32\findstr "["') do (set thisip=%%a)
```

I then want to take only the first 3 octetes and then add a custom one afterwards. For example if my thisip variable becomes 10.43.99.81 I want to use the following line to make that 10.43.99

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=. " %%a in ("%thisip%") do set ipfirst3octets=%%a.%%b.%%c
echo %ipfirst3octets%.71
```

Problem I'm having is that it does the first line perfectly fine but when we get to just taking the 3 octetes it closes the batch file. Even if I add a PAUSE at the end to make it hold so I can see the error is just closes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change here is in the last set command:

```
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping %computername% -n 1 ^| D:\Windows\system32\findstr "["') do (set thisip=%%~na.99)
```

`%%~n` will return the `name` part before the last period.